# Play Store won't update to newest version after resetting it back to factory version

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, updates, samsung-galaxy-j7

Like the title says, resetting the Play Store to its factory version caused it to be stuck on version 7.8.16.P. Tapping the update button downloads an update but then it doesnt change anything.

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime updated to Android 7.0 from 6.0 through official updates. The device is not rooted.

Has anyone experienced this problem or know of a way to fix it?

Comment: Try clearing its app data also the google app.  But it may ask for you to sign in again

Comment: Tried that, it remains stuck on the same version.

Comment: Tried instaling via an apk?  Its not recommend but then its worth a try.  Play store may be acting as if its already updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the refusal to update is because my ISP is issuing awful modems that start having issues after prolonged use, like dropping connections to Google services.